# Where is the Webdeploy script used by WebMatrix to publish a Wordpress Web Site

Tags: wordpress, webmatrix, webdeploy

I feel a little bit ridiculous but I cannot find where is the Webdeploy script used by WebMatrix to publish a Wordpress Web site. I would like to add some pre and post sync, exclude some files (to avoid the need to uncheck files at every publishing and risk a mistake every time)

The post [Using Web Deploy (msdeploy) to publish a WebMatrix site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868902/using-web-deploy-msdeploy-to-publish-a-webmatrix-site) is very interesting but it does not say where to put/modify the msdeploy.exe arguments.

Thank you